# Two-level grammar with ANTLR 3

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr3

I have a grammar which (if you simplify it quite a bit) looks like this:

```
options
{
    backtrack=true;
}

// parser
text: (TEXT)+;

and_level2_thing: text | '(' and_thing ')';

and_thing: and_level2_thing (OP_AND and_level2_thing)*;

and_expression: and_thing (OP_AND and_thing)*;

parse_starts_here: and_expression EOF;

// lexer
OP_AND : 'AND';
TEXT : ( '"' (~'"')* '"' );
```

It has two types of groups of expressions top-level (`and_thing`) and inner-level (`and_level2_thing`) for which different rules apply but both levels have to support AND e.g. `TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION` and 
`TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND (INNER_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND INNER_TYPE_EXPRESSION)`.

When I have a value of the form:

`(TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND (TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND (TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND (TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION))))`

the time starts to become exponential on the nesting level presumably because the AND is ambiguous. This expression evaluates instantly:

`TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION AND TOP_TYPE_EXPRESSION`

If you say this isn't a well designed language - I perfectly agree, but that's what I have right now :). Any ideas how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is ambiguous:

```
"a" AND "b"
```

can be matched as

```
parse_starts_here
  and_expression
    and_thing
      and_level2_thing
        text
      OP_AND
      and_level2_thing
        text
```

or as

```
parse_starts_here
  and_expression
    and_thing
      and_level2_thing
        text
    OP_AND
    and_thing
      and_level2_thing
        text
```

Normally, ANTLR would warn you about this ambiguity, but by declaring `backtrack = true`, you effectively tell ANTLR to try all alternatives and use first that matches.

On unambiguous grammars ANTLR runs in linear time. Use of backtracking leads to potentially exponential time. `memoize=true` is used to reduce the time back to linear at the cost of more memory used.

I would recommend removing the `backtrack=true` option. ANTLR will then tell you where the grammar is ambiguous. You can either remove the ambiguity, or if it is not possible, use syntactic predicates *only where needed* to prefer one possible match to the other. `memoize=true` would still help if you end up using syntactic predicates.

---

**Edit -** As to why there's backtracking even when both alternatives match:

It does not backtrack, but the time will still be exponential.

The problem is that ANTLR doesn't know it can match the first alternative until it actually tries to match it (since you didn't give it any hints). So it will first try to match the rule, and if it succeeds it will actually match it and perform all associated actions (`memoize` option avoids exactly this by remembering the particular rule succeeded for the given input position and not repeating the whole matching process).

Example:

```
"a" AND ( "b" AND "c" )
```

To match this, ANTLR must:

- Match `"a"`
- Decide whether the `AND` can be matched using the inner rule

  - To do this, it tries to match the inner rule
  - `AND` matches, `(` means go to `and_thing`
  - To match `and_thing`, it must:

    - Match `(` and `"b"`
    - Decide whether the `AND` can be matched using the inner rule

      - To do this, it tries to **match the inner rule against `AND "c"`**
      - The predicate succeeds - `AND "c"` matches the inner rule
    - **Match the inner rule against `AND "c"`**
    - Match `)`
  - The predicate succeeds - `AND ( "b" AND "c" )` matches the inner rule
- Match the inner rule against `AND ( "b" AND "c" )`

  - `AND` matches, `(` means go to `and_thing`
  - To match `and_thing`, it must:

    - Match `(` and `"b"`
    - Decide whether the `AND` can be matched using the inner rule

      - To do this, it tries to **match the inner rule against `AND "c"`**
      - The predicate succeeds - `AND "c"` matches the inner rule
    - **Match the inner rule against `AND "c"`**
    - Match `)`

AS the emphasized parts of the process show, ANTLR needs to match the text `AND "c"` four times to match the input, while there's one level of nesting. If there was another level, this whole process would repeat twice, so ANTLR would parse the last part eight times.

---

One related remark - if you use syntactic predicates rather than backtrack option, you can fine-tune what the predicate contains - in some cases it needs not contain the whole rule being predicated. In your example above, you could just tell ANLTR to use the `OP_AND and_level2_thing` rule whenever it encounters `OP_AND`, without needing to check whether `and_level2_thing` matches. Note that you can only do this because you know that either `and_level2_thing` will match, or the other alternative will fail as well. If you do this wrong you end up with the parser getting lost and refusing an input that would be valid if it chose the right alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Jiri Tousek . "ANTLR will then tell you where the grammar is ambiguous." - You mean at compile time, right? Here's some info on removing backtracking https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar . "tell ANTLR to try all alternatives and use first that matches" <- It was known that this grammar is ambiguous but that's what I didn't understand really. What's a case of something that would fail and need to backtrack on the case above? It seems to me that any interpretation would match.

Comment: It will report these when generating the grammar (not at your program's compile time per se - rather when generating the Java parser class).

Comment: I edited the post to answer the "Why does it still backtrack if the first alternative matches" - it does not backtrack, but the time is still exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Adding memoize "fixes" the problem. But I'm sure there's a better solution or some more interesting discussion around it.

```
options
{
    backtrack=true;
    memoize=true;
}
```